# jQuery Ajax post file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to post an uploaded file via ajax to php.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" />
<input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" />
<input id="CSVUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Submit" value="Hochladen" />
```

**JS**

```
$("#uploadForm").submit(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( 'csv',  $( '#csv' )[0].files[0] ); 
    formData.append( 'name', $( '#name'));
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "../lib/import.php",
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        success: alert('erfolgreich'),
        error: alert('Fehler'),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false
    });     
});
```

and then i try to get the form data in PHP:

```
$_FILES['csv']
$_POST['name']
```

But the Ajax call completes with success and error... I'm confused...
The PHP file will not executed correctly...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Both alert will be displayed. And because that, I think I become a success and error callback. Sorry, but how can I handle them? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't assigning functions to `success` or `error`.

You are *calling* the alert function *immediately* and then assigning its return value.

You need to create new functions to assign to `success` and `error`.

```
success: function () { alert('erfolgreich') },
error: function () { alert('Fehler') },
```

---

You are also calling the function as a submit handler, but aren't preventing the normal form submission. Consequently, the browser will load a new page before processing the response to the Ajax request.

```
$("#uploadForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try restructuring your AJAX call with your success and failure code like this:

```
$.post('../lib/import.php', formData).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('error');
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more examples.